# Floquet theory for periodic delay differential equations: current numerical routines

Tags: numerics, stability, numerical-modelling, differential-equations

I would like to determine the stability of a system of periodic delay differential equations (a seasonal host-parasite model). I've tried to implement the method described in Lemma 2.5 in this paper:

- [Liang, X., Zhang, L. & Zhao, XQ. Basic Reproduction Ratios for Periodic Abstract Functional Differential Equations (with Application to a Spatial Model for Lyme Disease). *J Dyn Diff Equat* **31**, 1247–1278 (2019).](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10884-017-9601-7):

> **Lemma 2.5** Assume that (E, E<sub>+</sub>) is an ordered Banach space with E<sub>+</sub> being normal and Int(E<sub>+</sub>) $\neq$ ∅,
> which is equipped with the norm ||·||<sub>E</sub> . Let L be a
> positive bounded linear operator. Choose v<sub>0</sub> ∈
> Int(E<sub>+</sub>) and define a<sub>n</sub> =
> ||Lv<sub>n-1</sub>||<sub>E</sub> , v<sub>n</sub> = $\frac{Lv_{n-1}}{
> > a_{n}}$, ∀n ≥ 1. If $\lim_{(n→+∞)}a_n$ exists, then r(L) =
> $\lim_{n→+∞}a_n$.

But I'm not sure it's working properly (I've probably made a mistake somewhere in the implementation). The problem is it doesn't always seem to correspond to equilibrium points I find when simply simulating the model for a very long time. I looked into different ways of approximating Floquet multipliers/monodromy matrices etc. for delay equations, just so I could double check my work, and there seem to be many different approaches (e.g., semi-discretization, finite element analysis, Chebyshev polynomials, etc.)

My question, for anyone much more familiar with this literature than I am, is: **Is there a currently preferred method? Are there any that are easy and quick to implement (I'm not a very sophisticated programmer or mathematician)?** I would be especially interested in an example with published code. Some advice would be greatly appreciated.